# how I send the start date and end date to oracle query in python

Tags: python, oracle

How do I send the start date and end date to the Oracle query in Pythonsee my code i am using Oracle 11g 11.2 xe verion

```
start = datetime.date(2003-06-17)   
 conn = cx_Oracle.connect('hr/hr@10.0.0.77/xe') 
 cursor = conn.cursor()
# cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE HIRE_DATE = :start", (start,))    # give error # 

  cursor.execute("""select * from employees where HIRE_DATE >= %s and date = %s """, (start, ))  # give error

cursor.execute("select * from employees where HIRE_DATE strftime('%Y-%m', Date) = ?", (start,))  # give error     rows = cursor.fetchall()        print(rows)    conn.close()
```

please give the right format that run in query
Thank you in advance

I tried to send the start date and end date in the Oracle query python

Comment: Before posting please check your code (and text)!  Also give a proper description of what you are trying to archive and the full error message.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bind variables in your SQL query. I have made some modifications in your code.

```
import cx_Oracle
import datetime

start_date = datetime.date(2003, 6, 17)  
end_date = datetime.date(2003, 6, 18)  

conn = cx_Oracle.connect('hr/hr@10.0.0.77/xe')
cursor = conn.cursor()

query = """
SELECT *
FROM employees
WHERE HIRE_DATE BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date
"""

cursor.execute(query, start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Here is the calender code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import Calendar

def get_selected_date():
    selected_date = cal.get_date()
    result_label.config(text=f"Selected Date: {selected_date}")

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Date Picker Example")

label = ttk.Label(root, text="Select a Date:")
label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

cal = Calendar(root, selectmode="day", year=2023, month=1, day=1)
cal.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
get_date_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Get Selected Date", command=get_selected_date)
get_date_button.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

result_label = ttk.Label(root, text="")
result_label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you very very much for your big help is running without any error

Comment: but sir I want to use a date selection calendar (Date pickers ) how to use it, please guide me

Comment: @mfahim I have implemented the calender code for you in my answer section. If you make the format accordingly. I hope your purpose will be fulfilled.

Comment: in the Oracle query, I use this date format    (2003, 6, 18)   -- datetime.date(2003, 6, 17) but the date piker former is 24/06/2023 how to convert the date picker format to this (2003, 6, 18) format for oracle query    ( by this command to_char(min(Transaction_Date),'DD-MM-YYYY) as MinDate,) or another command for date formatting  thank you in advance for your help

Comment: from datetime import datetime
date_str = "24/06/2023"
date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%d/%m/%Y")
year = date_obj.year
month = date_obj.month
day = date_obj.day
date_tuple = (year, month, day)
print(date_tuple)